# Drools Workbench - VFS Repository Clustering - Workbench Assets Not synched

Tags: cluster-computing, drools, apache-zookeeper, workbench, vfs

I am deploying Drools Workbench with VFS Clustering in place. I have followed the steps defined in Drools-6 documentation in section “VFS-CLUSTERING”, and the following link. But my repositories are not synching

http://mswiderski.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/clustering-in-jbpm-v6.html

but getting following Zookeeper exception.

NoNode for /jbpm-cluster/INSTANCES/nodeOne_11/MESSAGES/df7cda63-979b-47b2-ac9a-f2b218cb188

**Problem**
BPMN process created in Workbench-A is not getting Synched with Workbench-B. Following are the screen shots for the difference in project assets. Images attached in “ServerAssets.png”
 [image: Servers not synched. One server has one additional bpmn files.]

**DESIGN**

Architecture design screen shot attached.
[image: Architecture design]

**Helix Commands Startup and Cluster Setup**

```
1.       helix-core-0.6.3\bin>helix-admin.bat --zkSvr localhost:2199 --addCluster jbpm-cluster
2.       helix-core-0.6.3\bin>helix-admin.bat --zkSvr localhost:2199 --addNode jbpm-cluster nodeOne:11
3.       helix-core-0.6.3\bin>helix-admin.bat --zkSvr localhost:2199 --addNode jbpm-cluster nodeTwo:22
4.       helix-core-0.6.3\bin>helix-admin.bat --zkSvr localhost:2199 --addResource jbpm-cluster vfs-repo 1 LeaderStandby AUTO_REBALANCE
5.       helix-core-0.6.3\bin>helix-admin.bat --zkSvr localhost:2199 --rebalance jbpm-cluster vfs-repo 2
6.       helix-core-0.6.3\bin>run-helix-controller.bat --zkSvr localhost:2199 --cluster jbpm-cluster 2>&1 > /tmp/controller.log &
```

**ZooKeeper Setup**

```
    Changes done only in zoo.conf
1.       dataDir = /zooDir/zookeeper  (Not sure where this directory gets created as I could not find it in $zookeeper_home/)
2.       clientPort = 2199
```

**Work-Bench A Configuration: Standalone.xml**

```
 <property name="org.guvnor.m2repo.dir" value="D:\\Servers\\M2_REPO"/>
    <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.dir" value="D:\Servers\Drools-6-Deployment\repo"/>
    <property name="jboss.node.name" value="nodeOne"/>
    <property name="org.uberfire.metadata.index.dir" value="D:\Servers\Drools-6-Deployment\repo"/>
    <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.id" value="jbpm-cluster"/>
    <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.zk" value="localhost:2199"/>
    <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.local.id" value="nodeOne_11"/>
    <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.vfs.lock" value="vfs-repo"/>
    <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.autostart" value="false"/>
```

**Work-Bench B Configuration: Standalone.xml**

```
>   <property name="org.guvnor.m2repo.dir"
> value="D:\\Servers\\M2_REPO"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.dir" value="D:\Servers\Drools-6-Deployment\repoB"/>
>     <property name="org.kie.nio.git.deamon.port" value="9518"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.port" value="9518"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.port" value="8002"/>
>     <property name="jboss.node.name" value="nodeTwo"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.metadata.index.dir" value="D:\Servers\Drools-6-Deployment\repoB"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.id" value="jbpm-cluster"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.zk" value="localhost:2199"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.local.id" value="nodeTwo_22"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.vfs.lock" value="vfs-repo"/>
>     <property name="org.uberfire.cluster.autostart" value="false"/>
```

**Sync Error :**

```
14:44:19,780 ERROR [org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTask] (pool-18-thread-21) Exception while executing a message. java.lang.NullPointerException msgId: 939154ed-eedb-493f-a803-83883764276a type: USER_DEFINE_MSG: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.uberfire.metadata.io.IOServiceIndexedImpl.setupWatchService(IOServiceIndexedImpl.java:168) [uberfire-metadata-commons-io-0.3.1.Final.jar:0.3.1.Final]
        at org.uberfire.metadata.io.IOServiceIndexedImpl.getFileSystem(IOServiceIndexedImpl.java:126) [uberfire-metadata-commons-io-0.3.1.Final.jar:0.3.1.Final]
        at org.uberfire.io.impl.cluster.IOServiceClusterImpl$SyncFileSystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(IOServiceClusterImpl.java:919) [uberfire-io-0.3.1.Final.jar:0.3.1.Final]
        at org.uberfire.io.impl.cluster.helix.ClusterServiceHelix$MessageHandlerResolverWrapper$1$1.handleMessage(ClusterServiceHelix.java:289) [uberfire-io-0.3.1.Final.jar:0.3.1.Final]
        at org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTask.call(HelixTask.java:93) [helix-core-0.6.2-incubating.jar:0.6.2-incubating]
        at org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTask.call(HelixTask.java:50) [helix-core-0.6.2-incubating.jar:0.6.2-incubating]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

14:44:20,506 ERROR [org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTask] (pool-18-thread-21) Message execution failed. msgId: 939154ed-eedb-493f-a803-83883764276a, errorMsg: null
14:44:20,985 INFO  [org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTaskExecutor] (pool-18-thread-21) message finished: 939154ed-eedb-493f-a803-83883764276a, took 1260
14:44:20,995 INFO  [org.apache.helix.manager.zk.CallbackHandler] (ZkClient-EventThread-117-localhost:2199) 117 START:INVOKE /brms-cluster/INSTANCES/nodeTwo_22/MESSAGES listener:org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTaskExecutor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Jboss cluster should be configured in JBoss-Domain mode only.